# Switch to different XSLT Processor in ColdFusion

Tags: java, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10

I am using two different versions of ColdFusion, `ColdFusion 9` and `ColdFusion 10`, and there are different `XSLT Processors` in both.

`ColdFusion 9` is using `Apache Xalan` while `ColdFusion 10` is using `Saxon`.

So, is it possible to change the `XSLT Processor`?

**Or**

Can we use `javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory` class to switch to different processor?

Comment: I think you answered your own question. I found reference in the ColdFusion 10 release notes that you can use `-Djavax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=` to specify the parser to use. It is under known issue number 3167776 on [the release notes page](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/release-note/coldfusion-10-release-notes.html). It mentions for use with WebLogic but I don't know why it wouldn't work for other platforms.

Comment: I think Miguel's answer should have been an answer.  But a warning to anybody finding this question : Saxon 9 which ships with ColdFusion 10 is broken under java 1.8.  Fixed with [Saxon 9.5](https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/1944#note-3)

Answer (score 1):

You can exchange (also in coldfusion) the XSLT processor implementation by setting the following property:

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=qualified.name.of.TransformerFactoryImpl
```

... e.g. via (`-D`) JVM Parameter.

[TransformerFactory Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html):

> ... *The system property that determines which Factory implementation to create is named* `javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory`. This property names a concrete subclass of the TransformerFactory abstract class. I*f the property is not defined, a platform default is be used.*